# How to exclude column header from CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

When my client's are giving their inputs into the Excel file, they need the column header. But when they export the file into CSV (.csv) it includes the column heads into it. That's problem.

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
| Post id |  Name  | Designation |
+---------+--------+-------------+
    101     noYon      designer
    102     nakib     accountant
    103     nishi      developer
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

In my CSV (comma delimited) I got:

```
Post id,Name,Designation
101,noYon,designer
102,nakib,accountant
103,nishi,developer
```

I need to exclude the column heads (the first row) from the CSV when uploading it to MySQL using PHP.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: read the first line and discard it before reading the rest of the file line by line in a loop:

```
//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
fgetcsv($handle);  // Discard first line. If we know the maximum line length
                   // add it as second argument: it's slightly faster 

while( $data = fgetcsv( $handle) ) {
   $query = mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO table (post_id,name,designation) VALUES ('". 
                implode($data,"','")."'"; 
}
```

A faster solution which I've not coded here: append multiple sets of values to the `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 1):

With assistance of **[This article](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql)** and **[This forum thread](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10376604-PHP-import-CSV-and-skip-headers)** I came up to a viable solution  for me with personal assistance of my colleague Ms. Tahmina Aktar Nishi. Hope it will help anyone trying something like this:

```
        //get the csv file
        $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); // read the file
        ?>

        <?php
        // make the loop and do upload

        $find_header = 0; // a simple counter

        while( $data = fgetcsv( $handle,6000,",","'") ) {
            $find_header++; //update counter

            if( $find_header > 1 ) {
                $sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO table_name (
                        post_id,
                        name,
                        designation
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        '".$data[0] ."',
                        '".$data[1] ."'
                        '".$data[2]."'
                    )
                ");
            }
        } // endwhile
```

The logic is very simple and a bit childish. If we know how `fgetcsv()` works. `fgetcsv()` is:

> The `fgetcsv()` function parses a line from an open file, checking for CSV fields.
>
> The `fgetcsv()` function stops returning on a new line, at the specified length, or at EOF, whichever comes first.

That means it fetches each line of the CSV each time the loop rounds. So if we pass a simple PHP counter and exclude the first line, then it's that simple.

And of course, don't forget to sanitize the data using PHP sanitizing functions like `trim()` or `addslashes()` etc. :)

You can get my whole bunch of codes **[HERE](http://pastebin.com/tAdH0dPa)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    fgetcsv($file);
    while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== false){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($getData);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61908545/edit) your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.